# iCal php - how do I stop daylight saving?

Tags: php, icalendar

I have a script that generates an iCal feed from my database of dates. I finding that the script is adjusting the times for daylight saving - ie, all of the start times in the database are 21:00 but dates listed after the end of March are adjusted to 22:00...how can I stop this?...I simply want the times to show as they appear in the database and I don't want any adjustment for daylight saving or timezone (as the website is aimed at a UK audience).

```
mysql_select_db($database_name, $connection); // makes other mysql_ functions act on        this database
echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n"; //some static ical headers
    echo "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
    echo "PRODID:-//www.the-guards.co.uk gig bible ical feed v1//EN\r\n";
    echo "X-WR-CALNAME:Gig Dates\r\n";
    echo "X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/London\r\n";
    echo "X-WR-CALDESC:Private gig diary.\r\n";

$query  = " … "; /* [SQL Query] */

$result = mysql_query($query);
define('DATE_ICAL', 'Ymd\THis\Z');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo 
"BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n".
"UID:{$row['id']}\r\n".
"SUMMARY:{$row['location_name']}\r\n".
"DTSTART:" .date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime("{$row['starts']}"))."\r\n".
"DTEND:" .date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime("{$row['ends']}"))."\r\n".
"END:VEVENT\r\n"
;
}
echo  "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to set the timezone to a GMT+0 timezone for the runtime of your script:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
```

Then date() will not change the times anymore

Comment: ok, I've inserted that in the line after the '$result' declaration, but I'm still getting the same results....dates after the end of March have 1 hour added to their time.

Comment: Fixed - I needed to remove the 'Europe/London' references - all working now thanks!

Comment: Actually - this fixed the feed, all times are correct to the database - but when I pull the feed into ipad/Lotus notes/Outlook - I get the same problem. Entries for dates within the daylight saving part of the year (Apr-Oct) have 1 hour added to the time.

Comment: ...got it! Removed the 'Z'